# My CarouselViewControl block pinch and pan gesture in ItemSource

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel, gesture

I used CarouselViewControl (https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) in Xamarin.Forms with My Custom-View. My custom-view 
 was extended Contentview and was added Pinch & Pan Gesture Recgnizer.
custom-view's content is Image control in forms. 
I wanted to slide, pan-move and zoomable image gallery.
Gesture performance (pinch & zoom) was good.So , I added CarouselViewControl for sliding option. But , CarouselViewControl blocked my custom-view's Gesture
I don't know why blocked my Gesture-Recognizer.

I registered Recognizers in constructor

class Android_ZoomViewer : ContentView

{

....

public Android_ZoomViewer()
        {

```
        PinchGestureRecognizer pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += PinchGesture_PinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);

        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);


    }
```

}

in CarouselPage.xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CarouselPage : ContentPage
{

    public CarouselPage()
    {

           InitializeComponent();
```

var carousel = new CarouselViewControl();

```
            ObservableCollection<Android_ZoomViewer> list= new ObservableCollection<Android_ZoomViewer>();
            hymn.Add(new Android_ZoomViewer() { Content = new ImageView() });
            hymn.Add(new Android_ZoomViewer() { Content = new ImageView() });
            hymn.Add(new Android_ZoomViewer() { Content = new ImageView() });


            ((ImageView)hymn[0].Content).SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,"img1");
            ((ImageView)hymn[1].Content).SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "img2");
            ((ImageView)hymn[2].Content).SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "img3");

            carousel.ItemsSource = list;
```

in CarouselView, my Gesture Blocked ...

Comment: How did you add the sliding option? If you used `crolled` the in <cv:CarouselViewControl 
Scrolled="Handle_Scrolled">,then achieved `Handle_Scrolled` method?

Comment: All of option are related to sliding about  items.I think need to update native control in carouselviewControl's (Droid.viewpager , Ios.UIPageViewController)  Touch and fling Event. But it is very hard work  and so complex. I had done not find a way.